# JavaScript Deserialize could not Deserialize JSON Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I am posting JSON object through AJAX in my ASP.NET Application.

```
{
    "SaveData" : "{
       "TransactionType":"2",
       "Date":"8/10/2016",
       "BankAccountID":"449",
       "PaidTo":"Cash",
       "Amount" :"1551",
       "CheckNumber":"51451",
       "SupportingDocNo":"51521",
       "Remarks":"This is a remarks & this contains special character",
       "CheckPaymentID":0
    }", 
    "Type" : "Save"
}
```

In server side (I am using handler) I have set ContentType as application/json
and deserialize the SaveData object as

```
context.Request.ContentType = "application/json";
var data = new JavaScriptSerializer()
           .Deserialize<CheckPaymentsService>(context.Request["SaveData"]);
```

By doing this my SaveData object string get terminated unexpectedly at Remarks property as it contains & sign.

How should I handle this special character and other special characters such as <, > etc?

Comment: The "JSON" you've posted isn't valid JSON to start with, which probably doesn't help.

Comment: Got same error even after correcting JSON

Comment: Please show the corrected JSON... and ideally provide a [mcve]. As you're explicitly deserializing, you should be able to write a console app with the string and the deserialization call.

Comment: Now posted JSON is similar to as following.

{
  "SaveData": {
    "TransactionType": "2",
    "Date": "8/10/2016",
    "BankAccountID": "447",
    "PaidTo": "Cash",
    "Amount": "1551",
    "CheckNumber": "15155",
    "SupportingDocNo": "56",
    "Remarks": "This is a remarks &amp; this contains  special character",
    "CheckPaymentID": 0
  },
  "Type": "Save"
}

The way I have deserialize it is exactly given above. 

If I replace & with and it works. and I have  decorated CheckPaymentsService class with [Serializable] attribute

Comment: No, please *edit the post* instead of adding the JSON in comments... and then provide a [mcve]. We should be able to copy, paste, compile, run, see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to escape your json. The following code works fine for me.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string Json = @"{
        ""SaveData"": {
        ""TransactionType"": ""2"",
        ""Date"": ""8/10/2016"",
        ""BankAccountID"": ""449"",
        ""PaidTo"": ""Cash"",
        ""Amount"": ""1551"",
        ""CheckNumber"": ""51451"",
        ""SupportingDocNo"": ""51521"",
        ""Remarks"": ""This is a remarks & this contains special character"",
        ""CheckPaymentID"": 0
    },
    ""Type"": ""Save""}";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CheckPaymentsService>(Json);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CheckPaymentsService
    {
        public SaveData SaveData { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class SaveData
    {        
        public int TransactionType { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int BankAccountID { get; set; }
        public string PaidTo { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int CheckNumber { get; set; }
        public int SupportingDocNo { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public int CheckPaymentID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your provided json is not valid.

Here is the correct version (you can check it on http://jsonlint.com/) :

```
{
    "SaveData": {
        "TransactionType": "2",
        "Date": "8/10/2016",
        "BankAccountID": "449",
        "PaidTo": "Cash",
        "Amount": "1551",
        "CheckNumber": "51451",
        "SupportingDocNo": "51521",
        "Remarks": "This is a remarks & this contains special character",
        "CheckPaymentID": 0
    },
    "Type": "Save"
}
```

moreover illegal chars in json are

```
‘ single quote
” quote
\ backslash
```

Comment: Corrected the JSON format still got same error
@Quentin Roger